# column filtering using asc/dsc ? complex one . MVC4

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a datatable with data . i want to apply sorting . When i click one the table Header the Header index will be reached to controller where i have my method Like below .

```
public ActionResult AjaxHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
    var Lead_FullDetails = entityobj.Leads;
    IEnumerable<Lead> filteredLeads;
    filteredLeads = Lead_FullDetails;
    var isLeadNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_1"]);
    var isContactNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_2"]);
    var isCompanyNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_3"]);
    var isProductSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_4"]);
    var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);

    Func<LeadList, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 && isLeadNameSortable ? c.LeadName :
                                                  sortColumnIndex == 2 && isContactNameSortable ? c.ContactName :
                                                  sortColumnIndex == 3 && isCompanyNameSortable ? c.CompanyName :
                                                  sortColumnIndex == 4 && isProductSortable ? c.Product : "");

    var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc 
    if (sortDirection == "asc")
    {
        filteredLeads = Lead_FullDetails.OrderBy(orderingFunction); //HERE I AM FACING ISSUE its saying no orderby function present : erros mentioned below .

    }
    else
    {
          filteredLeads = Lead_FullDetails.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);
    }

    var DisplayedLeads = filteredLeads.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
    var result = from c in DisplayedLeads select new object[] { Convert.ToString(c.LeadId), c.LeadName, c.ContactName, c.CompanyName,c.Product };
```

My errors :

> **1)Error 1 :**   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and the best extension method
>   overload
>   'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.OrderBy(System.Linq.ParallelQuery,
>   System.Func)' has some invalid arguments
>
> **2)Error 2** Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' to
>   'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

Remaining everything is working fine . just sorting issue present . Any ideas .!

Regards

Comment: Change     var Lead_FullDetails = entityobj.Leads; to     var Lead_FullDetails = entityobj.Leads.ToList();

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem. ToList() method you are using just forces data loading from the database. The problem is in the delegate being used for sorting.

Comment: Same issue exists no change. i guess issue present in if/else block . But when i keep lead_fulldetails and dot means its showing me orderby . when i compile its throwing error like above ..

Comment: ok leskovar thats a nice insight and any work around will great .!
When i remove if/else loop and keep filteredLeads = Lead_FullDetails.OrderByDescending(c => c.LeadName); its working perfect .

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Func , you are saying that the input parametre is of type `LeadList` (possible problem) and the return type is string (this is ok). 
OrderBy needs a delegate that has a input parametre of type `Lead` (not list).

Maybe this solves your problem?

EDIT:
I suggest you edit your delegate to something like this: (it is important to specify that the input parametre of the delegate is of type **Lead** (not list of Leads or anything like that)

```
Func<Lead, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 && isLeadNameSortable ? c.LeadName :
                                              sortColumnIndex == 2 && isContactNameSortable ? c.ContactName :
                                              sortColumnIndex == 3 && isCompanyNameSortable ? c.CompanyName :
                                              sortColumnIndex == 4 && isProductSortable ? c.Product : "");
```